# No puedo hacer que me muestre las validaciones en lista

Tags: nodejs, validación, handlebars.js

**Hola!** Soy novato y ya busque por toda la web y consultas y no encuentro una solucion. Pido por favor que si van a responder tengan en cuenta que soy novato asi que no den por sentado terminologia. Aqui la cuestion. Tengo un formulario que le asigne validaciones por ejemplo que el campo nombre no este vacio y que debe tener como minimo 3 letras. Estoy haciendolo con node.js y express-handlebars por lo que tuve que hacer un helper para poder usarlo en vista. La cuestion es que el helper funciona pero me muestra los errores uno pegado al otro. paso dato codigo e info:
Helper:

```
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");


Handlebars.registerHelper ("filtro", function (arrayErrors, name) {
  if (arrayErrors !== undefined){
    let listado= []
    arrayErrors.forEach(campo=>{
      if (campo.param===name){
          listado+= campo.msg
          console.log(listado);
        }})
      return listado    
      }
    })
```

Aqui lo aplico en la vista:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <img src="imagenes/iconos/nombre.png"  width="45" height="45">
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-6" placeholder="Nombre" aria-label="Nombre" id="nombreContacto" name="nombre" autofocus value="{{datosFormulario.nombre}}">
 <span class="badge input-group text-uppercase fs-6 text-danger">
  {{#filtro arrayErrors "nombre"}}
<p>{{msg}}</p>

 </span> 

{{/filtro}}

</div></div>
```

y por ultimo una foto del resultado que no me sirve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo tu podrías suministrar más info , como por ejemplo cual es el error puntual que te arroja ?

Comment: osea la funcion anda pero lo que yo quiero es que me muestre por elemplo debajo de input de nombre los dos errores pero no pegados. que me los muestre asi:        *NOMBRE OBLIGATORIO       y debajo el siguiente error. ya probe ponerlo en lista, en parrafo en span, y muestra uno pegado al otro

Comment: y ya probaste colocarle un coma y un espacio como hiciste en el input de apellido?

Comment: Eso lo hice para que al mostrármelos juntos aparezca como un texto legible pero no es lo que intento hacer. Por lo visto nadie sabe cómo hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estás escribiendo `html` directamente, puedes usar la etiqueta `<br />`

```javascript
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");
Handlebars.registerHelper ("filtro", function (arrayErrors, name) {
      if (arrayErrors !== undefined){
        let listado= []
        arrayErrors.forEach(campo=>{
          if (campo.param===name){
              listado+= campo.msg + ' <br />' 
              console.log(listado);
            }})
          return listado    
          }
        })
```

Comment: Sabia que era algo muy tonto que estaba pasando por alto por novato. intente el br pero no lo estaba haciendo de manera correcta. GRACIAS! POR TU TIEMPO! POR TU AYUDA Y SOBRE TODO POR LA SOLUCION!!!!!!

Comment: Una consulta mas. ahora tengo que cerrar la pregunta o como se hace aqui?

Comment: Ya esta cerrada. Y no es una pregunta tonta!. Recuerda que "no hay preguntas tontas, hay tontos que no preguntan".